# Javascript .load doesn't see PHP's variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using the following script to load content on the page without refreshing it. The pages that I load this way should not be accessible as stand alone pages.

```
 <script>
    $(".toLoad").click( function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#page-wrapper").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
</script>
```

I have this in my index.php

```
define('SECURE', true);
```

and this in the other files

```
!defined('SECURE') and exit("Not allowed");
```

This system works very well with PHP's include or require functions but it blocks me from loading the pages from my index.php using the given javascript. What's the workaround or how could I restrict the direct access but allow it trough javascript on my main page?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with `how could I restrict the **direct access** but allow it **trough javascript** on my main page` ?

Comment: I mean that I would like to be able to .load the file from my index.php and at the same time the file should not be accessible via direct link access

Comment: You can't do that. `.load()` is just performing the same kind of `GET` operation that the browser does when you enter the URL in the address bar.

Comment: There are some headers that are sent when AJAX is used, but you can't depend on that -- someone can easily write a script that sends these headers.

Comment: @Barmar so one can't write a single page app that's secure? I just want to reload/ change only the content div and also have files restricted to direct access. I Guess I'll just keep doing it with require_once and constant check + full page reload.

Comment: How is it less secure if the user can view the page directly instead of inside the DIV? It's the same data.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I guess your right. The problem that I have now is that the pages loaded with javascript don't have access to the user's session. And I'm displaying custom data based on values from the session. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why they don't have access to the session. Are they being loaded from a different directory than `index.php`? You may need to use `session_set_cookie_parameters` so that the session cookie will be available in both directories.

Comment: @Barmar The files are in the same directory. Some of the files that I load via Js fetch data from mysql/ csv based on a user id that's stored in a SESSION variable at login.

Comment: Then there's no good reason why it doesn't have access to the session variables. Do the files you load start with `session_start()`?

Comment: @Barmar God, I'm dumb. Forgot to add it now that I load via Js. Before there was no need since the session was already started in the index.php and they were added via require_once(). Thanks a lot and I'm ashamed of myself lol.

Answer (score 1):

`define` declares a constant, which is accessible during the script operation (only to php which means only on server).

1. It is not a variable
2. It does not persist between page loads (so when You hit another php file, this is not defined).

As for disallowing hotlinking - You can check HTTP `Referer` for instance, but it can be fooled.

Comment: How about using session? When the js will load the page, will it do it from the current user's session?

Comment: If an open session exists - direct link from other site will work (as long as the browser is still open)... and it won't work for static files.

Comment: The problem that I have now is that the pages loaded with javascript don't have access to the user's session. And I'm displaying custom data based on values from the session. How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I've sort of fixed my problem. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a php-proxy thingy.. Then you `.load('jsproxy.php?url=' + $(this).attr('href'));`

I don't know php very much, but you should just define secure, and include the page in the url...

Comment: I've sort of fixed my problem. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send your secure variable from index page to next page and session should not be used for this purpose as it will allow direct access as session always enable on request of index page. But you can check request is xmlhttp (ajax) request or not from server with following function as load() function request with HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header with 'xmlhttprequest'.

```
 function isAjax(){
   return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
 }
 if(!isAjax())
  {
    echo "no direct access"; exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: I've sort of fixed my problem. Thank you for the answer.